# Bijection from the real numbers to the negative real numbers

Tags: functions, cardinals

I'm trying to construct a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{-}$. The only thing I've been able to find is $f(x)=-e^{x}$ and I was wondering if there is any other functions that work? Would I be right in assuming any function of the form $-a^{x}$ where $a\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ works?

Comment: Those are very natural choices.

Comment: Okay thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One branch of a hyperbola:
$$
f(x) = x - \sqrt{x^2+1}
$$

[image: graph]

Answer (score 2):

There are lots and lots of them.  Most cannot be described, but even among those that can there are many options.  You can compose your exponential with any bijection $\Bbb {R \to R}$ and get a new function.  You can take $[0,1_)$ to $[-18,-17), [1,2)$ to $[-783,790)$ and just generally jumble the pieces around.